# Dynamic form field autocomplete

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a asp.net web form which has a 'TemoinsVille' textbox input.
This field has jquery autocomplete feature:

```
 var auto5 = $('.temoins').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteTous", "InvForm")',
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 400
    }).data("ui-autocomplete");
    auto5._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .attr("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append(item.label.split("|")[0])
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
    auto5._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
        var that = this;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
        $(ul).addClass("dropdown-menu");
    };
```

This autocomplete feature works just fine when I only have one TemoinsVille input field.

I want the user to be able to dynamically add more 'TemoinsVille',in my Model(    InfoFormulaireADTModele.cs), TemoinsVille is a list of string:

```
        public List<String> TemoinsVille { get; set; }
```

I added the following code to let the user add more TemoinsVille:

```
$(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
                currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val('');
            controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function (e) {
            $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And in my view, the TemoinsVille part look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//...other fields

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="control-group" id="fields">
        <label class="control-label" for="field1">Témoins</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <form role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AdtFormModel.TemoinsVille, new { Class = "temoins" })                        
                       <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code, the autocomplete works but I can't add other VilleTemoins fields. I suppose the form tag is one of the problem. But if I remove it, the autocomplete stops working and I still cannot add another TemoinsVille.

If I put the code outside of the @using Html.BeginForm()), I am then able to add more TemoinsVille fields, but the auto complete works only on the first one and the value doesn't bind to the model.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First off all please remove `<form role="form" autocomplete="off">` from your View because `@using (Html.BeginForm())` is already a form tag,  So it good practice not to use nested  tag.

To add field in autocomplete list

Controller

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult AddNewField(string fieldName)
    {
        //Can make duplication check hear...
        TemoinsVille.Add(fieldName);

        //Hear make some database Or other means to persist data to store newly inserted field.
        //The reason we need to store field is that we won't be able to get this fieldname when you search same again in autocomplete.


    }
```

In JavaScript make call to AddNewField method

```
$(function () {
        $(".btn-add").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/AddNewField?fieldName=" + $(".temoins").val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope above suggestion may help you to resolve your problem